# Every connection in Interface Builder causes a SIGABRT!

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, sigabrt

I have three views that I switch between using a tab bar, and the two first views work as they should. The third view also loads and displays the images, labels, buttons, etc., I place there in IB. However, when I try to make a connection, for example between a label declared in the third view controller, and the label in Interface Builder, I get a SIGABRT error when trying to load the view. The log shows, among other things:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>        '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
>       this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.'

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, UIViewController will not respond to your customized keys of your subclass.
You should configure "File's Owner" to correct type of your view controller subclass in your Interface Builder.

Comment: Then check your main window xib for the tab bar's third view controller object. Hint: that view controller is of type UIViewController and should be set as ThridViewContrller (the class name you have chosen).